# Copy pasting geometry nodes from one object to another

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have 2 objects each of them with geometry nodes and I want to join them into one. When I copy paste from one geometry nodes to another the group input gets replaced by the existing one and I loose the correct inputs for the new nodes I pasted. How can I solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This is "normal" behaviour, because there can only be one group input node in one geometry node tree.

That's why Blender has to decide, which group input it takes.

You have to manually add your other input values to your existing group input node.

Comment: @lara Just to avoid misunderstandings: you can have many _Group Input_ nodes in a nodetree, as long as they are all duplicates of the original node. You just cannot have different _Group Input_ nodes.